# Accessing external database from a Spring application

Tags: spring, jpa, datasource

I have two projects in my workspace, projectA and projectB.

In projectA i have beans that construct a database with JPA with annotations on build. Lets name this database as dbA.

In projectB i need to access read and write into dbA.

Both projects are Spring projects.

Questions:

How can projectB know about beans in projectA? Can i access dbA with JPA(Hibernate) from projectB?
Now i am accessing to dbA from projectB with JDBC and explicit SQL queries. But i need to entityManager.merge entityManager.save and so. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- How can projectB know about beans in projectA?

By adding the beans in projectA as dependency to projectB.

- Can i access dbA with JPA(Hibernate) from projectB?

Yes you can.

- Now i am accessing to dbA from projectB with JDBC and explicit SQL queries. But i need to entityManager.merge entityManager.save and so. Is it possible?

Yes, it is possible after you add JPA related ocde to projectB or create a jar of the jpa beans from projectA and add the jar as a dependency to projectB.

Comment: Thanks very much. Can creating a jar and adding as a dependency be achieved by ant and a build xml? And how can i achieve that JPA not to build a new database from jar in projectB, and look at the dbA? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @tuxi - Yes you can use ant to build that jar. Tables are not created automatically by JPA so I doesn't think this is an issue.

Comment: Sorry for still asking but for Spring-JPA-entityManager usage i must add @Entity annotation to it, right? So on start up it builds the tables again. Where should i define not to build entities only access external db, on persistence.xml, or Spring's aplicationContext.xml . Thanks very much

Comment: @tuxi JPA doesn't build tables again. the underlying implementations like hibernate and ecplipselink however has options for creating the tables. Depending upon the implementation you are using, you can disable/enable them